# Is there a way to get the mouse position within the terminal?

Tags: node.js, terminal, position, mouse, cursor-position

I am currently coding a node.js program relating to mouse coordinates. Is there a way to see the mouse position in the terminal in Node.JS?

I've tried the ways beginning in `\e` but they only list the **cursor** position. How do I get the **mouse** position in the terminal?
[image: Example]

Is there a way to get said position in the "Row/Column" or "Column/Row" format? If there is no way, what about using `child_process`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.

To get events, the bash escape load `ESC[?100Xh`, replacing X with a number. The events will then be logged to the console.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at RobotJS it can show you where the mouse position is. You can use 'getmousepos' function to get the X and Y coordinates of the mouse on the screen

NPM:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/robotjs

Doc:
https://robotjs.io/docs/syntax#getmousepos

Comment: Thanks! By any chance is it possible to get the coordinates relative to terminal, like in the `row/column` format?